# Units in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know for integral domain $R$, units of $R[x]$ are units of $R$.

How about if we introduce a quotient ring? i.e., suppose I have an ideal $(x^2-1) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and quotients by this ideal. Note since $x^2-1 = (x-1) (x+1) $ and $-1,1\in \mathbb{Q}$ $x^2-1$ is reducible so $(x^2-1)$ is not a maximal ideal.

I wonder what is units of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-1)$.

Let $\bar{a} \in \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-1)$ be units. then $\exists \bar b$ such that $\overline{ab}=1$

\begin{align}
&\bar{a} = a + (x^2-1), \quad \bar{b} = b+ (x^2-1) \\
&\Rightarrow \quad \overline{ab} = ab + (x^2-1) = (x^2-1) 
\end{align}
then $ab\in(x^2-1)$, so $a$ can be either $c, c(x+1), c(x-1)$ where $c \in \mathbb{Q}$

Is this approach correct? How one can compute the units of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-1)$ in a formal way?

Comment: You could start by remarking that $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$ and using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: You're missing $a=x$, since $x^2=1$ in your quotient ring. Also, you should want $ab+(x^2-1)=1+(x^2-1)$, otherwise you're not finding units, but zero divisors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "chinese remainder theorem" proves the following: If $I:=(x-1), J:=(x+1)$  it follows  $IJ=(x-1)(x+1)=(x^2-1)$ hence there is an isomorphism

$$\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-1)\cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/I \oplus \mathbb{Q}[x]/J\cong R:=\mathbb{Q}\oplus \mathbb{Q}.$$

The units in $R$ are pairs $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}^*$.

**Question:** "How one can compute the units of $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2−1)$ in a formal way?"

**Answer:** There is a canonical map

$$u: \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-1) \rightarrow R $$

defined by

$$u(f(x)):=(f(1),f(-1))$$

hence $f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-1)$ is a unit iff $f(1),f(-1)\in \mathbb{Q}^*$.

**Example:** In general if a polynomial $p(x)=p_1(x)\cdots p_l(x)\in B:=\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a product of distinct irreducible polynomials $p_i(x)$, let $I_i:=(p_i(x))$ and $I:=I_1\cdots I_l$. It follows there is an isomorphism of rings

$$u: B/I\cong B/I_1\oplus \cdots \oplus B/I_l$$

with $u(f):=(\overline{f},.., \overline{f})\in B/I$. Hence

$\overline{f}\in B/I$ is a unit iff $\overline{f}\in B/I_i$ is a unit for all i. If $p_i(x):=(x-a_i)$ for all $i$ it follows $\overline{f}\in B/I$ is a unit iff $f(a_i)$ is a unit for all $i$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The elements of the quotient ring are of the form $a+bx$ with $a,b\in\Bbb Q$ and  $x^2=1$.

Consider the equation
$(a+bx)(c+dx)=1$, when $a+bx$ is given.

Then $(ac+bd) + (ad+bc)x=1$ and so $ac+bd=1$ and $ad+bc=0$.

This gives you two equation with two unknowns $c,d$. Solve them.